# How do you make POST request with a XML data body using HTTParty on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, request, httparty

I'm currently trying to make an api call to a server which just accepts my data in form of an xml.
I tried calling the service from postman and it works like a charm.

```
curl -v -X POST -H "x-apiKey: 83202136355d1704350fb3ef596ac126" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d '<Request LanguageCode="en" emailAddress="your email" mobileNumber="+4477....." gate="212" boardingHHMM="18:40" departHHMM="19:10" arriveHHMM="20:30" ffMiles="" DepartTerminal="Term 2" ffTier="" message="Sample" CabinName="Economy" > <Barcode firstName="Arie" lastName="van der Veek" title="MR" bookingRef="PNR123" depAirportCode="AMS" arrAirportCode="CDG" carrier="XS" flightNumber="56" depDate="2015-06-06" classCode="Y" seatNumber="21B" seqNumber="002" ffAirline="ZZ" ffNumber="123456789" ticketNumber="000123456789012" issuingCarrier="ZZ" /> </Request>' "https://dev2dbp.api.aero/api/ZZ"
```

Now I tried to implement this api call in Ruby on Rails using the following code, but sadly I'm getting an ERROR 500 everytime.

```
class FlightTicketController < ApplicationController

#  get 'flight_ticket/get_ticket'
def get_ticket
    response = HTTParty.post(
    "https://dev2dbp.api.aero/api/ZZ",
    :headers => {"x-apiKey" => "83202136355d1704350fb3ef596ac126","Content-Type" => "application/xml"},
    :body => '<Request LanguageCode="en" emailAddress="your email" mobileNumber="+4477....." gate="212" boardingHHMM="18:40" departHHMM="19:10" arriveHHMM="20:30" ffMiles="" DepartTerminal="Term 2" ffTier="" message="Sample" CabinName="Economy" > <Barcode firstName="Arie" lastName="van der Veek" title="MR" bookingRef="PNR123" depAirportCode="AMS" arrAirportCode="CDG" carrier="XS" flightNumber="56" depDate="2015-06-06" classCode="Y" seatNumber="21B" seqNumber="002" ffAirline="ZZ" ffNumber="123456789" ticketNumber="000123456789012" issuingCarrier="ZZ" /> </Request>' 
)

render xml: response
  end


end
```

Do you have any tips to make this work?

Comment: @Orions Is it clearer now?

Comment: The code is fine. It works for me.

Most likely the problem is not with the API call but with your controller. Is the 500 error from your controller or the API which is called?

Probably you should reset the API token.

If my answer does not help, please add some more details from the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the 500 error code is from your controller and not from the API call. If you check the log files you will see more details. I'm taking a guess:

You are handing a HTTP Response to `render` but ask it to render it as XML.

Try

```
render xml: response.body
```

instead.

Comment: Dude, you are truly my hero of the day!!!11!!1 May your day be as bug free and freezeless!

Comment: Glad this was helpful! If you check the logs of your application you will often see more details.

Perhaps you can mark the answer as correct then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe putting instruct tag at top of body can work,

```
:body => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Request LanguageCode="en"...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly I'm still stuck with my error

Comment: He sends the same XML with ```curl``` and there it works.